# How can I put dropdowns in cells of jQuery's Flexigrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexigrid

I need to put dropdowns in a cell of my jQuery Flexigrid for the user to change the data in Flexigrid own. How do I do this?

I need only knowing how to put the dropdowns in cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put any HTML object in a Flexigrid.

```
function Retornaddl()
{
    string linha = "<select class='inputlogininterno' id='resultadolista' name='resultadolista' style='width:150px;'><option value=''>Escolha...</option></select>";
    return linha;
}

var jsonData = new
{
    page = pageIndex,
    total = count,
    rows = (
        from item in pagedItems
        select new
        {
            id = item.ID,
            cell = new string[] {
                item.ID.ToString(),
                Retornaddl()
            }
        }).ToArray()
};
return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't. But you can make an edit button in the grid and display your edit stuff in a floting div.

Comment: i did brother, you can put any html iten in flexgrid, tomorrow maybe i put here.